# Tailwind css precendence

Tags: css, media-queries, tailwind-css

I am facing issue setting width of div for different screens. I made a class .vBox in tailwind.css

```
.vBox{
    width: 360px;
    min-height : 200px;
}
```

And used it in div

```
<div className="h-48 md:vBox w-full">
```

But the width is always full, according to w-full, for all media screens. I even tried

```
<div className="h-48 w-full md:vBox">
```

But same result. If i remove w-full, then width is according to vBox but i want w-full class width in mobile screens.

Comment: the class name "h-48 md:vBox w-full" and "h-48 w-full md:vBox" in same way. so you need to consider to add new class defined on tailwind css that works in responsive mode. one thing you should not define a spacific width for the div to get full width with responsive. full width div will never work if you define any individual width for it like 360px.

Comment: @BozlurRahman so how to make vBox responsive ? it is taking full width for all screens currently

Comment: You made `.vBox` as a utility or your just put `.vBox` in your css sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your custom `.vBox` class responsive you can define it as follow:

```
@variants responsive {
    .vBox {
        width: 360px;
        min-height : 200px;
    }
}
```

This will allow your class to be picked up by breakpoints prefixes, like `md:vBox` in your example.

Check the [generate responsive variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities#generating-responsive-variants) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to set various spacific width's for each spacificed device, you can do that by grabbing the screen width of the device by using `@media()` css function. i made a example for you in https://play.tailwindcss.com/gEgbhOvzH8?size=514x720&file=css
or you can check code snippet shown in below

```css
    .vBox{
    min-height : 200px;
    background: red;
}
@media (min-width:480px) {
    .vBox { width: 400px }
}
@media (min-width:640px) {
    .vBox { width: 600px }
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .vBox { width: 700px }
}
@media (min-width:1024px) {
    .vBox { width: 1000px }
}
@media (min-width:1280px) {
    .vBox { width: 1200px }
}
@media (min-width:1536px) {
    .vBox { width: 1500px }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="h-48 vBox w-full">
```

Comment: Thank you.. but this is old css way.. cant we get benefit of using tailwind

Answer (score -1):

You can use w-[100%] instead of w-full this will do the trick.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33031103)